# Laravel 5.1 validation rule alpha cannot take whitespace

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have created a a registration form where a farmer will input his name. The name may contain hyphen or white spaces. The validation rules are written in the `app/http/requests/farmerRequest.php` file:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name'     => 'required|alpha',
        'email'    => 'email|unique:users,email',
        'password' => 'required',
        'phone'    => 'required|numeric',
        'address'  => 'required|min:5',
    ];
}
```

But the problem is the `name` field is not allowing any white spaces because of the `alpha` rule. The `name` field is `varchar(255) collation utf8_unicode_ci`.

What should I do, so that user can input his name with white spaces?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can use a [Regular Expression Rule](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-regex) that only allows letters, hyphens and spaces explicitly:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name'     => 'required|regex:/^[\pL\s\-]+$/u',
        'email'    => 'email|unique:users,email',
        'password' => 'required',
        'phone'    => 'required|numeric',
        'address'  => 'required|min:5',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 58):

You can create a custom validation rule for this since this is a pretty common rule that you might want to use on other part of your app (or maybe on your next project).

on your **app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php**

```
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    //Add this custom validation rule.
    Validator::extend('alpha_spaces', function ($attribute, $value) {

        // This will only accept alpha and spaces. 
        // If you want to accept hyphens use: /^[\pL\s-]+$/u.
        return preg_match('/^[\pL\s]+$/u', $value); 

    });

}
```

Define your custom validation message in **resources/lang/*en*/validation.php**

```
return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Validation Language Lines
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The following language lines contain the default error messages used by
| the validator class. Some of these rules have multiple versions such
| as the size rules. Feel free to tweak each of these messages here.
|
*/
// Custom Validation message.
'alpha_spaces'         => 'The :attribute may only contain letters and spaces.',

'accepted'             => 'The :attribute must be accepted.',
 ....
```

and use it as usual

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name'     => 'required|alpha_spaces',
        'email'    => 'email|unique:users,email',
        'password' => 'required',
        'phone'    => 'required|numeric',
        'address'  => 'required|min:5',
    ];
}
```

Comment: where to find this `AppServiceProvider.php`

Comment: And don't forget to add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;` at the top of your `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` ;)

Comment: You can also use $this->app in service providers and add a third parameter as error message. Useful when translation isn't needed. $this->app['validator']->extend('my_rule', function ($attributes, $value, $parameters) { return (bool) preg_match(...); }, ':attribute my custom message.');

Comment: Did you try using string in your rules ?
`'name'     => 'required|string',`

Answer (score 8):

You can use [This Regular Expression](https://regex101.com/r/c64pSk/1) to validate your input request. But, you should carefully to write RegEx rules to implement.

Here, you can use this Regex to validate only alphabet & space are allowed.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name'     => ['required', 'regex:/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/']
    ];
}
```

I know, this answer may little bit changes with others. But, here is why I make some changes :

- Using array in rules. As mention in [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-regex), you should better using array as rules when using Regex.
- Using specified Regex for validate input request. Of course, you can selected answer above, but I recently found some bug with it. It allow [Empty Characters](http://emptycharacter.com/) to pass validation. I know, this might little bit *paranoia*, but if I found the better answer, why not using it?.

Don't get me wrong. I know, other answer is good. But I think it's better to validate everything as specific as we needed, so we can secure our app.